# Can't install npm on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: npm, ubuntu-12.04

I wanted to upgrade my nodejs and npm 1.4 to the latest. I managed to upgrade my nodejs to 10.0.40, but my npm could not update. So i decided to remove it all together and re-install the latest version. Now not only can i not install the latest version, but i cant install the one i have before. Every time i try install it gives me this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how can i install the latest version when i dont have it at all?

Comment: What does "I managed to upgrade my nodejs" mean? What exactly did you do? That's probably relevant information...

Comment: means i ugraded my node on my pc

Comment: That is not helpful. You're are seeking help and should do your best to provide all relevant information. What are the steps you took to upgrade? Did you install from source? Did you upgrade the debian `nodejs` package? Did you install from another ppa?

Comment: i am new at this, so i would ask for you to be patient. i want to install Grunt software, So for me to be able to install and run the Grunt version i need, the instruction told me that i need to install node js 0.10.28 or higher and npm 2.1.8. or higher. Now i managed to install a Node js v0.10.40. But i cant seem to upgrade the npm version i already have on my pc. am not sure how i upgrade the node js. i just followed instructions i found on the net. when i do the same with npm, i get that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the relatively limited information, I would recommend you fully remove and reinstall node from the NodeSource ppa.

That would be `sudo apt-get purge nodejs` to remove node, then follow [instructions here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions).

For Ubuntu, the full sequence of commands to uninstall and reinstall current nodejs + npm would be (node 4.x):

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

## Disclaimer

This is going to completely remove your installation of Node.js, then reinstall from another (up to date) source. This process should be straightforward, but if you don't understand what it's doing, use it at your own risk.

Comment: I was having so many issues with installing npm. Node would install but npm wouldn't for some reason. This was the only method that worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall package ,

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Update files ,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install it again

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

if there is some issue with audit

```
npm audit fix
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by restart my computer , sudo apt-get update, sudo apt install npm and it works now